# Suggested ways to take a screenshot of a react page

Tags: reactjs, pdf, report, dashboard

I have a react app that serves a live dashboard to clients (SPA).
Within that dashboard, I have what you might call a 'summary' page that gives the user a periodic summary (in a timeframe of their choosing).
Some of those users, want to receive a periodic report (a screesnhot of that summary) as PDF to their emails.

My struggle is with the report generation part - one thing that I'm trying is do is have an automated process login to my webpage and take a screenshot.
However, it feels not best-practice, and causes issues (the page has an MFA that I somehow need to bypass, etc.) .

Bottom line, I was wondering if there is a known process to do what I'm looking for.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using node for the backend you can try using https://github.com/mrafiqk/html-pdf-node this package?